# Would you like to read

Tags: sentence-meaning

Would you like to read this book?

Will you like to read this book?

Do you like to read this book?

How these 3 sentences mean the whole sentence differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to read this book? => Do you wish to read this book?

Will you like to read this book? => *If* you read this book, will you like it?

Do you like to read this book? => You *are* already reading this book. Do you like it?